# Show that $f$ has a fixed point at $\overline{B_1(0)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I really don't know how to start with this.  Can you please help me with this?

Suppose $\displaystyle{f: \overline{B_1(0)} \rightarrow \overline{B_1(0)}}$ is continuous and $f$ is analytic in $\displaystyle{B_1(0)}$.  Prove that $f(z)$ has a fixed point in $\displaystyle{\overline{B_1(0)}}$.

How to do this?  Please. I would appreciate any help.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is true by [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem), simply because $f$ is continuous. The fact that it is analytic on $B_1(0)$ does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jose Carlos Santos.